# Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-native-reanimated

so this is the first time I used Reanimated 2 and unfortunately my  App get crashed with the above message. Unable to view my app screen.

> Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.

I'm using reanimated here

```
import React from 'react'
import Item from '../../Common/Item'
import {View,Text,FlatList,StyleSheet , TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'

import Animated, {useAnimatedStyle} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {bin,mix,useTiming} from 'react-native-redash' 


const {interpolate,not}=Animated
const SectorItem=({sector,clients,index,opened,toggleSector})=> {
        const {name}=sector
        const ITEM_HEIGHT = 100
        const transition = useTiming(opened)
        const style = useAnimatedStyle(()=>({
          height: mix(transition,0,clients.length * ITEM_HEIGHT)
        }))
      
        //here we wll also have the clients of each sector 
        return <Item xStyle={styles.item}>
                <View>
                    <Text>{name}</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={e=>toggleSector(index)}>
                      <Text>open</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <Animated.View style={style}>
                    <FlatList 
                       data   = {clients}
                       style  = {{...styles.Clientlist,display:opened?'flex':'none'}}
                       contentContainerStyle = {props =>(styles.flatList)}
                       showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                       renderItem   = {({ item }) =><Item xStyle={{marginBottom:8}}> 
                         <TouchableOpacity>
                           {/* redirect to client  */}
                              <Text>{item.name} </Text>
                         </TouchableOpacity>
                       </Item> }
                       keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    />
                </Animated.View>
        </Item>
   
}

export default SectorItem
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    list:{
        borderColor:'#fff',
        padding:16,
    },
    Clientlist:{
        borderColor:'#fff',
        padding:16,
    },
    flatList:{ 
        alignItems: 'center',
         justifyContent: 'center', 
         height:200,
         flex:1
    },
    item:{
        marginBottom:8
    }
  });
```

my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "DistributionApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.11.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.13.0",
    "@rematch/core": "^2.0.0-next.10",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.0.6",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.20",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "react-native-redash": "^16.0.8",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: getting same error...did you find any solution?

Comment: yeah did you enabke Hermes ?

Comment: no matter whether Hermes is enabled or disabled, I am getting this error. What should I exactly do? what version of `reanimated` should I exactly use?

Comment: did you include hermes plugin in ``` babel.config.js```

Comment: I have included `react-native-reanimated-plugin` in babel.config.js. But I am not sure about hermes engine plugin. Can you tell me what it is?

Comment: [Joshua Nwankwo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11482122) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66709376) saying "Please their official documentation, it solved mine https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation/"

Answer (score 5):

reanimated package is not auto-linked in android, please follow the steps mentioned on the official documentation.

You need to make changes in
android/app/build.gradle

```
project.ext.react = [
 enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

add following in babel.config.js

```
plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
```

add following in MainApplication.java

```
    @Override
    protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
      return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage(); // <- add
    }
```

Comment: follow the steps mentioned here
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation/

Comment: really is not auto linked ? that wasn't mentioned in the docs , is it ?

Answer (score 2):

I've downgrande `"react-native-reanimated": "2.0.0"` to `"react-native-reanimated": "1.13.0"`,

Past in terminal `yarn add react-native-reanimated@1.13.0` or
`npm install react-native-reanimated@1.13.0 --save`

Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was because I didn't installed pods.I solved it by moving to ios directory and running pods install

```
cd ./ios
pod install
```

Comment: Also works for `macos`. You could update your answer

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced the same issue with React Native `^0.64.0` and react-navigation `5.x`

Reanimated dependency `"react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0"` as stated in the official documentation requires some additional configs, including ***babel***, ***Hermes***, and ***MainApplication.java***

Please follow the official documentation to resolve [React Native Reanimated](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation)

> requires additional steps apart from just adding a dependency to
> package.json

After making changes make sure to clear gradle and yarn( or npm ) caches

Answer (score 0):

following an official guid helped me [doc](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation/)

Answer (score 0):

Running `npx react-native link react-native-reanimated` fixed the issue for me.

Appears that this added the following line to ios/Podfile:

`pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'`

Answer (score 0):

**For iOS**

> Notes: Im using Xcode Version 13.4.1 (13F100) and running the app in Mac M1.

I think this error is same like what i got, i got this error :

`Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'ImageLoader' could not be found`

And i fix the error with add `arm64,amv7` at Exclude Architectures -> Debug -> Any SDK

[image: xcode config Exclude Architectures]

Answer (score 0):

### iOS Fix:

If you are facing this issue while running for iOS device, try running `pod install` inside the `ios` folder
It worked for me.

---

Inside your project root directory:

`cd ios`

`pod install`

After this `cd ..` back to your root directory and run your project, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

i had same experience using react-native-webview. just apply rebuild the application and re-run it.. the problem will be solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

android

> npm install react-native-gesture-handler 
> npx react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
> npx react-native run-android

ios

> npm install react-native-gesture-handler
> npx react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
> cd ios && pod install && cd ..
> npx react-native run-ios

Answer (score -1):

```
Error - TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated'
Cause - React Native Reanimated 2.0
```

I got this `TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated'` error and I found the solution:

***Step 1*** - Download react native project from github: **https://github.com/software-mansion-labs/reanimated-2-playground**

***Step 2*** - Then run command

```
npm install
react-native start
react-native run-android
```

and build app.

***Step 3*** - when it works, move your required project files and install your required npm pakages.

***Step 4*** - Then run commands

```
npm cache clean --force
cd android
gradlew clean    
gradle cleanBuildCache    
gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
cd..
npx react-native start --reset-cache
npx react-native run-android
```