# React-native: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761015/invariant-violation-turbomoduleregistry-getenforcing-nativereanimated-c) was already asked but no response there. I am asking once again as I am hoping some one might came across this issue recently.

I have installed `react-native-reanimated 2` and as soon as I ran the app got following error

> Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes

Can some one help me to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
Error Solved 

**Error - TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated'**
Hello,
I got this[TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated'] error and i found the solution 
Step 1 - Download react native project from github  "https://github.com/software-mansion-labs/reanimated-2-playground".
Step 2- Then run command 
=> npm install
=> react-native start
=> react-native run-android
and build app 
Step 3- when its work move your required project files and install your required npm pakages.
Step 4 - Then run commands
=> npm cache clean --force
=> cd android
=> gradlew clean
=> gradle cleanBuildCache
=> gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
=> cd..
=> npx react-native start --reset-cache
=> npx react-native run-android
its work for me try once.
```