# Getting error in Latest version of React-native-reanimated -- TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-reanimated, react-native-drawer

I am am trying to create Drawer-navigation in my application. for that that i am using "react-navigation-drawer" library but it has dependency of "react-native-reanimated"

I have installed "react-native-reanimated^2.0.0" and run the project than it gives me this error and blank screen on emulator

ERROR  Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761015/invariant-violation-turbomoduleregistry-getenforcing-nativereanimated-c)

Comment: Hi Chirag! I noticed a similar question to yours was asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761015/invariant-violation-turbomoduleregistry-getenforcing-nativereanimated-c
There's also a github issue on the Reanimated repo: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1127